# How to automate variable selection in glmnet and cross validation

Tags: r, glmnet

I am learning the use of `glmnet` and `brnn` packages. Consider the following code:

```
library(RODBC)
library(brnn)
library(glmnet)
memory.limit(size = 4000)
z <-odbcConnect("mydb") # database with Access queries and tables

# import the data
f5 <- sqlFetch(z,"my_qry")

# head(f5)

# check for 'NA'
sum(is.na(f5))

# choose a 'locn', up to 16 of variable 'locn' are present
f6 <- subset(f5, locn == "mm")
# dim(f6)

# use glmnet to identify possible iv's

training_xnm <- f6[,1:52] # training data
xnm <- as.matrix(training_xnm)
y <- f6[,54] # response

fit.nm <- glmnet(xnm,y, family="binomial", alpha=0.6, nlambda=1000,standardize=TRUE,maxit=100000)
# print(fit.nm)

# cross validation for glmnet to determine a good lambda value
cv.fit.nm <- cv.glmnet(xnm, y)

# have a look at the 'min' and '1se' lambda values
cv.fit.nm$lambda.min
cv.fit.nm$lambda.1se
# returned $lambda.min of 0.002906279, $lambda.1se of 2.587214

# for testing purposes I choose a value between 'min' and '1se'
mid.lambda.nm = (cv.fit.nm$lambda.min + cv.fit.nm$lambda.1se)/2

print(coef(fit.nm, s = mid.lambda.nm)) # 8 iv's retained

# I then manually inspect the data frame and enter the column index for each of the iv's
# these iv's will be the input to my 'brnn' neural nets

cols <- c(1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 20, 25, 38) # column indices of useful iv's

# brnn creation: only one shown but this step will be repeated
# take a 85% sample from data frame
ridxs <- sample(1:nrow(f6), floor(0.85*nrow(f6)) ) # row id's
f6train <- f6[ridxs,] # the resultant data frame of 85%
f6train <-f6train[,cols] # 'cols' as chosen above

# For the 'brnn' phase response is a binary value, 'fin'
# and predictors are the 8 iv's found earlier
out = brnn( fin ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8, data=f6train, neurons=3,normalize=TRUE, epochs=500, verbose=FALSE)
#summary(out)

# see how well the net predicts the training cases
pred <- predict(out)
```

The above script runs OK.

My question is: How can I automate the above script to run for different values of `locn`, that is essentially how can I generalize getting the step: `cols <- c(1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 20, 25, 38) # column indices of useful iv's`. At present I can do this manually but cannot see how to do this in a general way for different values of `locn`, for example

```
locn.list <- c("am", "bm", "cm", "dm", "em")  
for(j in 1:5) {
this.locn <- locn.list[j]
# run the above script
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like any testing with your data is possible, but you should immediately learn that using "(" after a token makes R look for a function by that name. Probably want `locn.list[j]`. The `j<-1` line appears completely superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for comment DWin: my bad, typo, and yes I agree j <- 1 is redundant!

Comment: Thanks for comment DWin: my bad, typo, and yes I agree j <- 1 is redundant! There is no problem running the code as I mentioned, my question was how to generalize the collection of the useful variables from glmnet after cross validation. At present I use the code many times per day using live financial data for one value of 'locn'. I could make a separate script for all 17 values of 'locn' and run them in series but I was hoping to capture the line beginning: cols <- c(1,...... programmatically rather than have to manually input this line in for each 'locn'.

Comment: You should edit your question when you agree that errors are in your code. I'm interested in the problem if you can see your way clear to make the dataset available.

Comment: Thanks DWin, I have editted my post as you suggest.

Answer (score 13):

Since posting my question I have found a paper by Simon, Friedman, Hastie and Tibshirani: Coxnet: Regularized Cox Regression which addresses how to extract what I wanted.

Some relevant details from this paper and adapted for my data (except for symbol for lambda!):
We can check which covariates our model chose to be active, and see the coefficients of those covariates.

```
coef(fit.nm, s = cv.fit.nm$lambda.min) # returns the p length coefficient vector
```

of the solution corresponding to lambda =cv.fit$lambda.min.

```
Coefficients <- coef(fit.nm, s = cv.fit.nm$lambda.min)
Active.Index <- which(Coefficients != 0)
Active.Coefficients <- Coefficients[Active.Index]

Active.Index # identifies the covariates that are active in the model and
Active.Coefficients # shows the coefficients of those covariates
```

Hope this may be of use to others!